# Chess.com API request not working when using Python Wrapper

Tags: python, chess

I'm trying to retrieve various data from the Chess.com API using Python. I came across a pretty intuitive wrapper documented [here](https://chesscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but when I try to run any of the given functions I keep getting a ChessDotComError due to the API's response.

Here is the original code:

```
from chessdotcom import get_leaderboards

def print_leaderboards():
    data = get_leaderboards().json
    print("Success!")

print_leaderboards()
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\witte\Documents\VS Code\chessdotcom-scraper.py", line 7, in <module>
    print_leaderboards()
  File "c:\Users\witte\Documents\VS Code\chessdotcom-scraper.py", line 4, in print_leaderboards
    data = get_leaderboards().json
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\witte\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\chessdotcom\client.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return cls.do_get_request(func(*args, **kwargs))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\witte\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\chessdotcom\client.py", line 112, in do_get_request
    return _do_get_request(resource)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\witte\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\chessdotcom\client.py", line 78, in _do_sync_get_request
    raise ChessDotComError(
chessdotcom.types.ChessDotComError: <class 'chessdotcom.types.ChessDotComError'>(status_code=403, text=<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en-US"><head><title>Just a moment...</title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"><meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><link href="/cdn-cgi/styles/challenges.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body class="no-js"><div class="main-wrapper" role="main"><div class="main-content"><noscript><div id="challenge-error-title"><div class="h2"><span class="icon-wrapper"><div class="heading-icon warning-icon"></div></span><span id="challenge-error-text">Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue</span></div></div></noscript></div></div><script>(function(){window._cf_chl_opt={cvId: '2',cZone: 'api.chess.com',cType: 'managed',cNounce: '2570',cRay: '7ff6ba7f2d87adb0',cHash: '5eca551eeebf8dd',cUPMDTk: "\/pub\/leaderboards?__cf_chl_tk=TOjNMnBQA2uWEKBQ6Ogbi8NTAMvz8ex0SiOvzj3T.kA-1693500165-0-gaNycGzNCrs",cFPWv: 'b',cTTimeMs: '1000',cMTimeMs: '0',cTplV: 5,cTplB: 'cf',cK: "visitor-time",fa: "/pub/leaderboards?__cf_chl_f_tk=TOjNMnBQA2uWEKBQ6Ogbi8NTAMvz8ex0SiOvzj3T.kA-1693500165-0-gaNycGzNCrs",md: "3JHIck3F0nZeQZpWQ.KJj_VB7BuKIOP28zUXwcRt7rQ-1693500165-0-Ae1oLSDeZ7LWV1ec3PqOkc4dXjzfUJZY9w6Nv2UJPei-MglHKwBxDS9sxN8SwalLYJDWW7WxQ_cwUto6nCuHqfthewug-i8r0vsKxjDp-zLyFcOPPUOHb4BegCxBCkkmbJHieaDX2fM-5V6pJ5gCkKiVp3NTaerWw-fxMMN1S9BGV7gsEeC9-01y6M37Lq8mAbxAqrC_nt6_H7ADip8A6WI2zyGPhqbwYd4ddUNragaMjeoXgkA9-AovrYWYsibQt4VCyo0XtVG4fs7Qpsxw_XQVRB7CEz2wgMpYdAJ9EiDPi3Bx3HyFuNq480uVg1kfj0mNeTaFPe9CdAOfMXyySTCjD9lnWHRLncP1DLuqq6GwDwakFK87sAP0BWZIjKFXPJXscp-ybk9uCB1mWTtIl_hwHjuFf_nMajdpGcfPcx_KR1ShlqYU_PF5noGJZ11LJiZvxIa9of0yvsIoBBeqj6HH5uTrFr9YT_5WNfSTCwlB59LlrbGc8Ci3NJ-l3UjT33Yw6C9G2L44EbMt3TNn-K5qMSYL54Sg0PXZbd0wuyL1fW8h5eWb9cwKwtuAHzrPIZt5GdRTW046TblivxLNXsHe76O-Tk00gZ7BDTGmJL0T6l81pav_yIYgVmq6dxIeZ2z0HQvc5EH3KBjLvP3hWv2UrtOJtfDun9l44ptxIF35WQSTU9poNYSz81tKKS0oWIUPy-JBQZe0sUqxnf2DtTfw9qH7pC-haaQ4dH-FuQyz47_Zk4mFFoXxzWtql__J0fY76VkyZ0UJbV_dWzvfn8ny0ad-yg4aPzNscl6tZx8ojYjwsuviP2hLixH_uzgtHLNo_mV2owV981Hm829sEJ-wI7WuDVvs4Sm8awGfoSs1OCLCnD6QBTeNOLLWv-iORdfho0ILo1xK51svRdnl7ypP-ve5WmoIwZEIKXsH_Q9Zar9LsUcroRaOpNLb8OlVEFg9p3ftlkL3gNZEu9qGFIutu9xvczQoZOANY0gEjucLXx6oFLWPkQ_8q7EXcpHb0v6TnpwJXV2Q4kFVEt5HRAFzcfwnAg_UPlvxlbUrc-gYwgnR8KlaqLU11NH0eFwh1c_ZzdQrG0YdTu-aTxF730hNxrG5QX5Ql04L_L-sV1IwvFuIxHxJ1ogIcJp6CZZtEwqoN94NkJ64BVSZX_71jH4Pgd1791DbF8FLgGvc3xanSzG5n4I9Kb_-_RhO4PmTzCzDp4rqvpIJxX0myy5ZmD3h-7gdpAIirv5wYPXZt4wjGDNJIwJf-I6MMwnRIpv2EsmSSdf5hs9BQ1i7gSGfuoxyS23k6hHnUtJIPwT8YfhghojG2EuSKsVwMDRdzxPbwFwKt2JxPpdNNtTbvACMTkoUEPTFr9ZU0LLKZnmp2ngctYg4RnoAFe4ehZATZk3_IBWnBqN8E_pYGRwVeLKD1eIKku2hJBQIe_QY_U8dzqtxK5xXlu7GmV3SDRa7X__OwzJFaf1G2q6t6MfSgcg-M8cS7cUg0lBWPffxqHaBwsrVzGLoAXJcGOqrYi1kPgoF2Lqo8nibfiSGPtVOZHxtGLrq2Dmq9KIT65VfxqaBZBPNhf19NFZ_d91sawMpA2GcnDdWXqKTo_aqYguxxT6svD7MCbjuOCAuKr5eZg256EQeYSHRbf-tuyb_tlmEIxbIs5T0SQfc65kkgjqOWihyqS0_tD7TAf2-0BT5nrVHvD9Xb2YMwZXHe3YlRQ8E_TbVAJay9ZxY4Aw4HVxhxF9-SUAbKhC03jfU7SFbeqhjbF8Khh1HSWvflK2rFYsFc9vHGrpQ_vQMmrAHEI7ZENRNpcki34dx8eEic_zze7AQduRQ6qVDRBzJAeg-U2iUVVPLVDhbfuzp2wZFdEOvtME2n0SZecST1Z0SANGIEQSpUf9_pw83J8fC2VnWAClLdTdy6GPKCSAUttipAjpr7vyLdcyjN5YhQXm-yxXG6vVF8syKIDV-TeTGwbJgmWHi3Mk7tQdgO-b-_ZPZ4ZQUN0yyUBS7DgTmCRilhzayL02oC3MB1Zbui1m_Zt3d6y2x97kJcjC4zTEWg3mRoLWcWI7nwmra3PCpENkZCzT047ixDQmw0AQeLGY6Yq7zqE3V324FHLqjzKvjcrB2k_JrfoP5oOs59JYeGBX55t7mZsqJDTLtFVGAMX4Hnm4rf5igJ6edowmqfvXH8Ybtv3GALIEIPvoN6MInuTwSNu4AMPE5uWsmXtiXgiZfDWljyOtnqneTpdi_fHFIohFz6E5ch8bwwW-tv3dmJTPGtRo94TXRItxE8D-Hmj38wa7UL_N_F5HbSWBWQpTz2_Ri-Mb0W1H6NuqCZKQJcs-y3qQ1XjRQIUSfmwz57BQC9VQBR9EnLx7EKGJpKZUTFXjRvWn4VXE_eYb8ylQKPqxS-mrxEW5tbtuuouicEdFCxttY8yvFHnZYYfDzowp3Jt5CFKlWlJlDWxYZH_ram0cF_uTzLFQz7cSaJtE985P4cJZacYXtMXB1hnZzU4nJyFonSgdqX0PXfM16pOkCcRMhsRTVK7y25cJyUiIZo5JN0XpwYxLWHmMTR3t4wVLoFB6v6Se5m740_W60UdOt0tYaumbdK1Np09Q08gATfB8P_WyMQsBNl38dJjV4DhA-o85SoPcn-LFXVZzK2sun4iJc3RkRsRfgujNuEWSwj8fo6toC3q29UYXe9A",cRq: {ru: 'aHR0cHM6Ly9hcGkuY2hlc3MuY29tL3B1Yi9sZWFkZXJib2FyZHM=',ra: 'cHl0aG9uLXJlcXVlc3RzLzIuMjguMA==',rm: 'R0VU',d: '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',t: 'MTY5MzUwMDE2NS4wMTEwMDA=',cT: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),m: 'K2G193aVCGWGcnKDpHpputd1TGHd61bNMnRqOWa6dT8=',i1: 'mrAtGCdZrjcMWlOO0SwwTg==',i2: 'MVr+a0vkRBArrUubL8Y5zw==',zh: 'mQFfcmIV15X+HE0ijfrq3Z1ehKRcjJIGDhfUaKSYuM8=',uh: 'KXOU42hMUUNBCj8raB/cd2As9NbLMb3/GhNBEShv6ew=',hh: 'EGuE0ahtNILIszXIr11UvFRQh2K7u6ykBalHqwDQljU=',}};var cpo = document.createElement('script');cpo.src = '/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/b/orchestrate/chl_page/v1?ray=7ff6ba7f2d87adb0';window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash = location.hash === '' && location.href.indexOf('#') !== -1 ? '#' : location.hash;window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery = location.search === '' && location.href.slice(0, location.href.length - window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash.length).indexOf('?') !== -1 ? '?' : location.search;if (window.history && window.history.replaceState) {var ogU = location.pathname + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash;history.replaceState(null, null, "\/pub\/leaderboards?__cf_chl_rt_tk=TOjNMnBQA2uWEKBQ6Ogbi8NTAMvz8ex0SiOvzj3T.kA-1693500165-0-gaNycGzNCrs" + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash);cpo.onload = function() {history.replaceState(null, null, ogU);};}document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cpo);}());</script></body></html>)
```

Here is documentation of a ChessDotComError ([source](https://chesscom.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/latest/pdf/)):

```
exception chessdotcom.types.ChessDotComError(status_code: int, response_text: str, headers:CIMultiDictProxy)

Variables
• status_code – Contains the status code of the API’s response.
• json – Dictionary representation of the API’s response.
• text – API’s raw response decoded into a string.
```

In the API response I see it says "Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue", but I'm not sure how to do that or if that's what's causing the issue. Is anyone else having trouble using this wrapper or the chess.com API? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That message is embedded within a `<noscript>` element in an HTML document.  I don't see what it has to do with the error.  What even is the error?  All I see is a stack trace which indicates that an external library (`chessdotcom`) raised an error (of type `ChessDotComError`), but I don't see an actual error message or anything else indicating what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks David, I added some extra info to clarify the issue. I think the ChessDotComError is only raised when the API doesn't return the proper data, such as here where there is a 403 status code. Based on the API's response I'm guessing that enabling javascript/cookies might be the issue, but not totally sure.

Comment: Copy everything after the `text=` on the last line of the error message into a file and save it as `err.html`. Then open that file in your browser. What does it say?

Comment: The HTTP 403 error is "Forbidden".  Perhaps chess.com now requires a login.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi When I exported the title is "Just a moment..." and the message is "Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue"

Comment: The html contains javascript that should have built the page, but I guess it doesn't work. Like Tim says, the HTTP error code (403) indicates that you are not allowed to access that URL, so maybe it requires a login or an API key? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403

Comment: Ah yes, I'd missed `status_code=403` but that's the most important piece of information here.  It means [the target server is disallowing the request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403).  You may need to include some authorization to use that service.  But the main point is that what you *thought* was the problem, and thus what you've been looking for information on and asking about, is entirely the wrong thing.  Instead, you'll want to look into why the service isn't authorizing the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [wrapper's documentation](https://chesscom.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/latest/pdf/) there's two methods listed for retrieving data. I was initially using synchronous API requests, but when I switched to asynchronous requests I got it working.

BTW - Make sure to use `await` instead of `asyncio.run()` in the last line of their example in 3.2.2